# MethodInfo.CreateDelegate with async Task return type

Tags: c#

I have this method,

```
public void SomeMethod() { ... }
```

And I can create delegate using reflection without issue,

```
var action = (Action)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this);
...
action.Invoke();
```

However, if I replace the `void` to `async Task` return type, I get this error,

`Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.`

I cannot find the way how to create the delegate and invoke it if the method is like this,

```
public async Task SomeMethod() { ... }
```

or like this,

```
public async Task<SomeObject> SomeMethod() { ... }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Think of Action like a void Method and Func<T> like a Method with return type. Seeing as you have Task or Task<T> as return type in your async method you need to use Func as shown by TheGeneral.

Comment: Yeah, I should have use Func<> instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly

Given

```
public async Task SomeBob() { ... }
```

I guess you are looking for

```
MethodInfo method =  //<Some wonderful reflection here>
var bob = (Func<Task>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Task>), this);

await bob();
```

or

```
(Func<Task<SomeType>>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Task<SomeType>>), this);
```

<sub>*Though as to way you are doing this or need to do this, I am not sure*</sub>

Comment: oh my... I try using Action<Task> instead of Func<Task>. :( Thanks.